# Disable Caching in Symfony CMF

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony-cmf

I am working on a project with symfony 2.6.9 and Symfony CMF to build a content management system.

The user has a function where he can change his pagename. 
Every time he edits the pagename I have to clear symfony cache to see the changes but I don't want to do that!

So my question is: 
**How can i disable all caching in Symfony CMF?**

Answer (score 0):

We have a caching layer in Jackalope Doctrine DBAL, there is none in Jackalope Jackrabbit. The one in Jackalope Doctrine DBAL should clear itself on any write atm, so it should not require a manual cache clear.

Maybe there is a bug there but there might be something else going on there. Can you test the following: rename a page and then use the "doctrine:phpcr:node:dump" command to see if the rename is visible.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. In our parameters.yml we had two caching entries relating to phpcr. 
I had to remove those two entries and now it works like expected :)